# Sql server query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me with my problem in Sql Server 2014?

I have this data in one table:

```
ID    Service   Price    Paid
1      Test1     100      
1      Test1     100      N
2      Test2     200      N
2      Test2     200       
2      Test2     200
```

What I'm trying is to present data like this:

```
ID     Service    CountOfPaid  CountOfUnPaid Difference
 1      Test1          1             1            0
 2      Test2          2             1            1
```

I can found Count of Paid or Count of Unpaid separately by grouping, but I can't found out how can I present data like i want. I also tried Union and sum from count(*) but that dont help either.

Thank you in advance for your help

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT  ID ,
        Service ,
        SUM(t.CountOfPaid)
FROM    ( 

(SELECT   ID ,
                    Service ,
                    COUNT(*) AS CountOfPaid
           FROM     TEST
           WHERE    Paid IS NULL
                    OR Paid <> N'N'
           GROUP BY id ,
                    Service)

          UNION

          ( SELECT  id ,
                    Service ,
                    COUNT(*) AS CountOfUnPaid
            FROM    TEST
            WHERE   Paid IS NOT NULL
                    OR Paid = N'N'
            GROUP BY id ,
                    Service
          )
        ) t

GROUP BY t.ID ,
        t.Service
ORDER BY t.ID ASC;
```

Comment: Hint: Do a GROUP BY.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh while OP goes of to get an attempt, no doubt someone will spoon feed them an answer and all hope is lost, and the cycle continues...

Comment: @jarlh I do have Group By in each separately query but I cant figure out how to achieve joining that 2 separate queries togather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working code

```
SELECT
    *
   ,ABS(Z.CountOfPaid - Z.CountOfUnPaid)
FROM (SELECT
        ID
       ,Z.SERVICE
       ,SUM(CASE
            WHEN paid = '' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS CountOfPaid
       ,SUM(CASE
            WHEN paid = 'N' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS CountOfUnPaid
    FROM #table Z
    GROUP BY id
            ,service) Z
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, its working... I just replaced case with if

Answer (score 1):

`Try This it will help you`

`DECLARE @table AS TABLE
(
id INT,
service  VARCHAR(50),
price DECIMAL(18,2),
paid varchar(1)
)
INSERT @table
SELECT '1' ,'Test1', 100, null UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,'Test1',  100 ,'N' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'Test2',  200 ,'N' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'Test2',  200 ,null UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'Test2',  200 ,null`

`;
WITH    temp
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        service ,
                        price ,
                        ISNULL(paid, 'Y') paid
               FROM     @table
             ),
        temp2
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        temp.service ,
                        COUNT(*) Total,
                       'PaidTotal' AS recordtype
               FROM     temp
               WHERE    temp.paid = 'Y'
               GROUP BY temp.id ,
                        temp.service
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   id ,
                        temp.service ,
                        COUNT(*) Total,
                        'UnpaidTotal' AS recordtype
               FROM     temp
               WHERE    temp.paid = 'N'
               GROUP BY temp.id ,
                        temp.service
             )

    SELECT  Id, pvt.service,
    ISNULL(PaidTotal,0) PaidTotal,ISNULL(UnpaidTotal,0) UnpaidTotal, (ISNULL(PaidTotal,0) - ISNULL(UnpaidTotal,0)) AS Difference
    FROM    temp2 PIVOT (SUM(temp2.Total) FOR   temp2.recordtype IN ([PaidTotal],[UnpaidTotal] )) AS pvt`

Answer (score 0):

Do condition aggregation

```
select id, service,
       sum(case when paid is null then 1 else 0 end) [CountOfPaid],
       sum(case when paid = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) [CountOfUnPaid],
       (sum(case when paid is null then 1 else 0 end) - sum(case when paid = 'N' then 1 else 0 end)) [Difference] 
from table
group by id, service
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
Select ID, Service ,
,Sum(Case When Paid='N' Then 0 Else 1 End) CountOfPaid
,Sum(Case When Paid='N' Then 1 Else 0 End) CountOfUnPaid
,Sum(Case When Paid='N' Then 0 Else 1 End) -
 Sum(Case When Paid='N' Then 1 Else 0 End) Difference
From Table 
Group by ID, Service 
Order by ID, Service
```

Answer (score 0):

If Paid is either 'N' or null:
`count(*)` counts all rows, `count(column)` counts rows where column is not null:

```
select id, service,
       [CountAll] - [CountOfUnPaid] [CountOfPaid],
       [CountOfUnPaid],
       [CountAll] - 2 * [CountOfUnPaid] [Difference] 
from
(
    select id, service, count(*) [CountAll], count(paid) [CountOfUnPaid]
    from tablename
    group by id, service
) dt
```